# Hibernate criteria by a list of natural ids

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am trying to create hibernate criteria using a list of natural ids. I saw the example here 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#query-criteria-naturalid but it only shows an example for querying a single record:

```
session.createCriteria(User.class)
  .add(Restrictions.naturalId()
    .set("name", "gavin")
    .set("org", "hb"));
```

Is there a better way to make a criteria for a list of natural ids than the example below?

```
Junction junction = Restrictions.disjunction()
  .add(Restrictions.naturalId()
    .set("name", "gavin")
    .set("org", "hb"))
  .add(Restrictions.naturalId()
    .set("name", "jdoe")
    .set("org", "rh"));         
session.createCriteria(User.class)
  .add(junction);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, no. The reason is due to the limitations of SQL in some implementations. When you try to phrase this in SQL it gets tricky...

Pseudo SQL that isn't cross DB supported...

```
select * from table where (name, org) in values ( ('gavin', 'hb'), ('jdoe', 'hr'))
```

What Hibernate ends up writing is the common cross DB way of...

```
select * from table where (name = 'gavin' and org = 'hr') OR (name = 'jdoe' and org = 'hr')
```

I have upvoted this question and added to my favorites to track in hopes that I am wrong and there is a better way. I know in DB2 for zOS this oddity also causes the optimizer to make poor choices.

Comment: Hi Andrew. 9 years later, would you know if it is possible ;-).